# How I get to know my downloading and uploading speed of internet programmatically in android

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi, 3g

I want to develop an application which tells me my downloading and uploading speed and also name of the network whether it is 3G, 4G, WIFI or etc.
Same appilcation idea to develop like Speed Test.net

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get download speed in android device or mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252656/how-to-get-download-speed-in-android-device-or-mobile)

Answer (score 3):

May be this [JSpeedTest library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib/) is of some use

Answer (score 1):

To avoid being called in static instance -

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo != null) {
    Integer linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),linkSpeed.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
WifiManager wifiManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo != null) {
    Integer linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
}
```

see below link:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252656/how-to-get-download-speed-in-android-device-or-mobile

below is demo code:-

http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=47

Comment: Can you guide me step by step how Speedtest.net is doing?

Comment: What is the case of uploading?